# Ajax jquery: One page site built from different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've seen an [article](http://www.awwwards.com/seo-optimization-for-parallax-scrolling-websites.html) where they advised to break up one page sites in to multiple pages for SEO. I've done this by using Ajax.load

```
$( "#target-location-content" ).load( "pagename.html #resource-content");
```

To make sure users will see the one page site instead of the single page, I changed navigation links with JavaScript to make them point to the id on the page.

```
var mainNavA = $("header nav a");
for(var i = 1, len = mainNavA.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var name = "index.html#content-" + mainNavA[i].attributes.href.value.split(".")[0];
    mainNavA[i].href = name;
}
```

Beside this, I expect needing to to redirect user accessing pages directly via search results or the url.

I can solve this with:

```
document.location
```

and check if the index file is in the path. If it is not, I can direct them to the index file.

```
var url = document.location.href.search("index");

if(url < 0)
    document.location = "http://localhost:8888/projecten/dewilg/index.html";
```

The code is working as expected. I´m just wondering:

Is this is a good solution for the given problem?
Are there are better ways to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have pointed out, you already have a solution for your scenario. Now, I believe you should have several pages then and load the desired content on server-side, not in your client-side. It is not a good idea to use AJAX to load the main content of your page.

If you load the main content of your page using AJAX, then:
- the user goes to the page
- the browser sends a request to the server
- the server responds to the browser
- the client-side of the page determines what to load and then sends another request to the server
- the server responds

If you determine what you load on the server-side, then:
- the user goes to the page
- the browser sends a request to the server
- the server responds to the browser

In the first case you are sending two requests to the server, while in the second case you send a single request to the server. Taking into account the fact that server requests are expensive, that is, they take a lot of time, we can easily reach to the conclusion that from performance's point of view it is better to determine what to load on the server-side, not with AJAX requests. Also, if you have ajax requests, then the scripts sent to the client-side can be viewed by your users and they can see how you handle your resources. This could be giving too much information to your users about how you operate.